# Highlighting a part of a series in Candles chart

Tags: vue.js, apexcharts

In my project, I use Apexcharts to display a candle bars chart. Actually, many of them. But I need to be able to highlight a certain part of the candle series on the chart. I couldn't find a way in the docs. Maybe there is, but not that straight, like maybe splitting the series in two and displaying them with different colors?

The latter, though, I've tried and it looks like it breaks the chart, because they dont not even look like a single series anymore, with weird offsets and missing candles.

Can someone at least give a hint how to achieve highlighting on a series?

Comment: Do you expect anyone to have a clue on how your data looks like and what's the design you're going for without showing what you have?

Comment: Yes, asking about some particular chart of some particular library, whose are properly named and tagged by me, I expect someone who actually has a clue what is "Apexcharts" and what is "candle bar".

Comment: I use apex-charts quite a bit and I'm guessing you're after something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vkWMC.png). Since I was able to do it for line charts, there are chances I might be able to achieve it for candle bars as well. Also, since you're the one needing help and I'm the one providing it, I'm expecting you to help me help you. The least you could do is provide a *runnable* [mcve], showing what you've got so far.

Comment: You clearly do not understand that my question is not depending on what I do, but what is possible to do with the chart library I use.

Comment: You were absolutely right, it's not possible with the chart library you use. It's only possible with [the one I use](https://i.stack.imgur.com/an9XK.png). Might have to do with me not understanding. Clearly.